# hiding and unhiding many divs one by one with a single button

Tags: jquery, hidden

part-1: I want to fade out an unknown number of divs one by one each time a button is clicked, those divs all have the same class attribute.

Part-2: when they're all hidden I want the same button to fade them in again one by one and so on back and forth.

I managed to create a working script but it seems too sloppy and it lags at the end of the second part.  so is there a better approach for this kind of effect?

```
var divCount = $('.box').length;
var visible  = divCount;
var hidden   = 0;
var check    = true;
var counter  = 0;


$('.button').click(function() {

if (hidden < divCount && check == true ) {
    $('.box').eq(counter).fadeOut('slow');
    counter ++;
    hidden ++;
    visible --;
} 
else { check = false; }

if (visible < divCount && check == false ) {
    $('.box').eq(counter-1).fadeIn('slow');
    counter --;
    hidden --;
    visible ++;

}
else { check = true}

});
```

and here's a copy of the file http://jsfiddle.net/vtgr2dns/

Comment: Please ask a more concrete question than "any suggestions". What exactly isn't working the way you want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use this technique which is a bit more complicated than the other ones but it doesn't require the engine to loop through all the visible/hidden elements (which could be 5 or 1000) each time the button is clicked

```
    var divCount = $('.box').length;
    var visible = $('.box:visible').length;
    var hidden = $('.box:hidden').length;
    var check = true;
    var counter = 0;

$('.button').click(function() {

    if (visible == divCount) {check = true}
    if (hidden  == divCount) {check = false }

    if (check) {
        $('.box').eq(counter).fadeOut('slow');
        visible--;
        hidden++;
        counter++;
     }

    if (!check) {
        $('.box').eq(counter - 1).fadeIn('slow');
        visible++;
        hidden--;
        counter--;
    }

}); // end click
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I give you a more simple approach, so you can get rid of the variables:

```
var divCount = $('.box').length;
var check    = true;
$('.button').click(function() {
    if($(".container .box:visible").length == divCount){
        check = true;
    }
    if($(".container .box:visible").length == 0){
        check = false;
    }
    if(check == true){
        $(".container .box:visible:first").fadeOut("slow");
    }else{
        $(".container .box:hidden:last").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I just toggle a class of hidden on each item. I need to know if I'm going forward or backwards. If I hit the wall (no results returned) then I change direction. I put it into your jsfiddle and it seemed to work.

```
var goingForward = true;
function fade(o){
    if (goingForward)
        $(o).fadeOut('slow');
    else
        $(o).fadeIn('slow');
    $(o).toggleClass('hidden');
}

function processClick() {
    var item = $('.box' + (goingForward ? ':not(.hidden):first' : '.hidden:last'));
    fade(item);
    return $(item).length;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        if(processClick()==0) {
            goingForward = !goingForward; //switch directions and go again
            processClick();
        }
    });
}); // end ready
```